# Why does the selection disappear when clicking on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, selection, rangy

I'm using the following code to edit a text in contenteditable div by changing its font. when clicking on a div which is a stylized dropdown menu the selection disappears in chrome. It works fine in firefox, opera and even in IE!

Rangy doesn't find any selected text to deal with. I'm wondering why!

**Note:** it works fine when using 'mouseover' instead of 'click'

```
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dt.on('click', function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            if (savedSel) {
                rangy.removeMarkers(savedSel);
            }
            savedSel = rangy.saveSelection();
            savedSelActiveElement = document.activeElement;
            return false;
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One workaround is to use the `mousedown` event rather than the `click` event and preventing the default behaviour.

```
obj.dt.mousedown(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if (savedSel) {
        rangy.removeMarkers(savedSel);
    }
    savedSel = rangy.saveSelection();
    savedSelActiveElement = document.activeElement;
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NJuMK/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should save the selection data before the click happens. For example, save it on the mouse over, and use it when the user clicks.

Comment: still losing the selected data when clicking